# Docker doesn't create files in specified volume

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-volume

I created this little demo program to show the problem I'm having.

```
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    create(".", "1");
    create("", "2");
    create("app/usr", "3");
    create("/usr/app", "4");
    create("usr/app", "5");
}

public static void create(String location, String name) {
    try {
        File myObj = new File(location+ "/" + name + ".txt");
        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I'm using this Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /usr/app/demo.jar
WORKDIR /usr/app/
VOLUME /usr/app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo.jar"]
```

these commands to build the container

```
mvn clean package
docker build -t please/work .
```

and last but not least this command to run the container

```
docker run please/work -v /root/hayasaka:/usr/app/
```

I've also tried using this

```
docker run please/work -v /root/hayasaka:/
```

but in both cases no files get created at /root/hayasaka

This is the console output I get when running the container

```
File created: 1.txt
File created: 2.txt
An error occurred.
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.create(DemoApplication.java:23)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
File created: 4.txt
An error occurred.
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.create(DemoApplication.java:23)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

In theory 1.txt or 2.txt should be created in the specified volume. Oh, also I created the project using the Spring initializer, as the real project also was created using that tool. As optional dependencies I only selected the Developer tools and I did not change anything in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Docker options like `-v` need to go _before_ the image name; anything after the image name gets passed as additional arguments to the entrypoint (technically it replaces the `CMD` in the Dockerfile).  Try printing out `args` in the `main()` function to see this.

Comment: The failures `app/usr/3.txt` and so on have intermediate directories in their paths. Those directories don't exist (anywhere -- this isn't to do with Docker per se) and `createNewFile` doesn't appear make the necessary directories. Try `File.mkdirs` as a first step. On the other hand `/usr/app/4.txt` *does* work because it is an absolute path to something that does exist as far as the running Docker container can see.

Comment: @mrblewog although that wasn't really my concern at that moment, thank you very much for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT**: To make this answer complete, I am adding what is already mentioned in a comment on the question. The fact that the `-v` switch on the `docker run` command is not positioned correctly.

The overarching reason that your execution is not behaving as expected here, is simply that the `-v /some/path` switch is appended to the end of the `docker run` command, after the image name.

`docker run --help` produces this input syntax description:

```sh
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Here it states that `[OPTIONS]` must be provided before the name of the image. All option switches are preceeded with a single or double `-`, and for most cases follwed by a parameter to the switch. And so the `docker` binary will identify the first argument to the `docker run` commnand, that is **not** preceeded with `-` as the name of the image.

Arguments follwing the name of the image, will be interpreted as an overriding command (`[COMMAND] [ARG...]`), and be appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` defined in the `Dockerfile` from which the image was built.

You have defined the `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo.jar"]
```

And given that the first example execution you provide is this:

```sh
docker run please/work -v /root/hayasaka:/usr/app/
```

The resulting command executed in the container will then be this:

```sh
java -jar demo.jar -v /root/hayasaka:/usr/app/
```

This is of course not your intention. And if the program probably does not expect any arguments, it will simply disregard them.

Here's an overview of your input and the outcomes.

### File `1.txt`

```java
    create(".", "1");
```

This will become `./1.txt`, or in absolute terms `/usr/app/1.txt`, which is a fine and valid path. The file `1.txt` will be created in the working directory of the java process, which in turn is the working directory of the user that initiates the java program, which you have set in the `Dockerfile` to be `/usr/app`.

### File `2.txt`

```java
    create("", "2");
```

This will create the file `/2.txt`, a file in the root of the filesystem in the container. given that only the directory `/usr/app` is volume mapped, this file will not be visible from outside the container.

### File `3.txt`

```java
    create("app/usr", "3");
```

This would create the file `app/usr/3.txt`, which is a location relative to the working directory of the java process. The absolute path is `/usr/app/app/usr/3.txt`. This fails, most likely due to the missing intermediate directory structure `app/usr`. Use this approach to resolve the issue:

```java
    if (!myObj.getParentFile().exists()) {
        myObj.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

That will create the missing intermediate directories.

### File `4.txt`

```java
    create("/usr/app", "4");
```

This will create the file `/usr/app/4.txt`, an absolute path that exists, since the docker build will create it with the given `Dockerfile` definition. No problems here.

### File `5.txt`

```java
    create("usr/app", "5")
```

This attempts to create the file `usr/app/5.txt`, which like the file `3.txt` is a location relative to the working directory of the java process. The absolute path is `/usr/app/usr/app/5.txt` It will fail for the same reasons that `3.txt` fails.

I hope this provides a good overview!

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much, this will come in real handy. But the actual problem was solved by David Maze. But still useful. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the position of the volume mapping switch - I should probably put that in the answer for anyone who comes across this question. Glad to be able to help

Comment: Mine is positioned correctly but files are still not being created :(